# How to Open New window of Edge browser instead of new tab in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried below so far,

1. Process.Start("microsoft-edge:", "--new-window" + url);
2. Process.Start("microsoft-edge:", url" + "-new-window");

Above code opens new windows but its empty not having url I am passing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
var url = "https://www.google.com";
var arguments = "--new-window " + url;
Process.Start("msedge", arguments);
```

Source: [Launch Edge in a new window from the command line](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/msedge_open-msedge_win10/launch-edge-in-a-new-window-from-the-command-line/d06f0b8b-ae25-4b8b-b1c1-1db069ed7582)